# Jupyter: Access denied error when starting kernel in spyder / jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, spyder

After an "update -all" in anaconda and in particular spyder to 4.0.1, spyder and jupyter are no longer able to start a kernel given the error appended below (prior to the update everything was working fine).

I've tried running anaconda, jupyter, and spyder as admin. I've reinstalled all anaconda components individually and anaconda itself. I've also restarted my pc several times. Windows 7.

The error from jupyter notebook:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 476, in write_connection_file
    kernel_name=self.kernel_name
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 141, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 424, in secure_write
    win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
  File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 375, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
    win32security.SetFileSecurity(fname, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sd)
pywintypes.error: (5, 'SetFileSecurity', 'Access is denied.')
```

The error from spyder:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 1173, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle, **kwargs)
File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
self.write_connection_file()
File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 476, in write_connection_file
kernel_name=self.kernel_name
File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 141, in write_connection_file
with secure_write(fname) as f:
File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 424, in secure_write
win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
File "D:\Chris\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 375, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
win32security.SetFileSecurity(fname, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sd)
pywintypes.error: (5, 'SetFileSecurity', 'Access is denied.')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this same exact error issues with the latest version of jupyter-client on Windows Server 2016, throwing "Access is denied" errors when starting the kernel.

From what I can tell: Jupyter is trying to set a permission on a file in our user folder (e.g `C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Roaming\jupyter`).  And for some reason, we don't have permission to edit the permissions of files in this folder - thus Jupyter doesn't have permission either and it fails.  One can get around this by telling Jupyter to allow these files to be "insecure".  In your command prompt, after activating your environment and before launching Jupyter do this:

```
set JUPYTER_ALLOW_INSECURE_WRITES=1
```

Then:

```
jupyter notebook
```

And now hopefully your kernel will launch.

This GitHub issue was most relevant in finding the solution: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4907#issuecomment-588536184

Answer (score 0):

This problem also had me stymied. After several hours of research on this and other solutions, I found the solution from elsewhere. However, in the interest of making this more visible, here it is for those coming here. Note that this is very similar to dartagan's solution above.

I set a global environment variable. On our network, this works for each user-computer combination. So, if a student changes computers, that student will need to reapply the solution.

1. Find where to set global environment variables in Windows (a search
   on the computer will show it quickly)
2. Create a new variable named JUPYTER_ALLOW_INSECURE_WRITES
3. Set the value of this variable to 1

That's all.

If it is, I hope to hear why this solution is problematic.